# Akka Stream Java - is it possible to merge unknown amount of sources into one

Tags: java, akka-stream

I have a Slick source, that produces multiple sources:

```
 Source myBigSource = Slick.source(slickSession, sqlQueryString,
     (SlickRow row) -> {
          return (Source)createNewSource(row, someContext);
     }
 );
```

How can I concatenate sources produced by createNewSource into one big source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flatMapConcat or flatMapMerge:

```
Source myBigSource = Slick.source(slickSession, sqlQueryString,
    (SlickRow row) -> {
        return (Source)createNewSource(row, someContext);
    }
).flatMapConcat((o) -> o);
```